# How to store week days + time in the database

Tags: laravel, forms, bootstrap-4

I am building app on Laravel, I am totally new on it, basically i want to add week day + time to database, but no idea what datatype to choose and how to make it in HTML form.

I have university clubs, where they have specific week day and time of trainings: So for example: as a admin i want to set weekday from dropdown list: like monday and set time 6p.m, and moreover i want to have add function like if I have more than 1 training i press "+" and add another day and time and store it in database;

questions

1. what column do i need to create in my table of mysql
2. what to write in controller
3. how to create form

Comment: In database you should use Datetime format. For working with dates in laravel you should read about Carbon.

Comment: i dont need date, I only need to store week day and time for example Monday 9p.m , it is like training session, like on monday training at 9.pm and on wednesday at 6p.m like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two php inbuilt functions

strtotime() and date()

For the database column kindly use  DateTime

*** Here is how you can do it ***

```
$date_to_go_in_db = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($string_date_from_date_picker));
```

To show date from db with days and Time such as 26th Monday june 2pm etc use this

```
date('Y-m-D g:i a', strtotime($dataobject->event_date_time_from_db));
```

Comment: if you don't want to make it dynamic flexible then you can just use VARCHAR in db and fetch As Is

Comment: i dont need date, I only need to store week day and time for example Monday 9p.m , it is like training session, like on monday training at 9.pm and on wednesday at 6p.m like this

Comment: okay i get it , i suggest you use date('D',strtotime($string_date_from_date_picker)); which returns something like Tuesday     Then use date('g:i a',strtotime($string_date_from_date_picker)) which returns something like 2pm then concatnate the two variables and store in a VARCHAR column in DB

Comment: Otherwise you can statically loop the seven days of a week to a select option and statically also loop all the hours in a 24hr clock and then concat  them at the point of insertion and insert in a VARCHAR column